# Making Google Reminders show today's items in my notification drawer

Tags: google, google-calendar, google-tasks

I currently use Google Tasks (Google Reminders' predecessor) with an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.teamtasks.tasks.paid) that displays today's items in my notification drawer so I don't forget about them.

I'd like to switch to Google Reminders so that I can see everything within the Calendar app. However, it doesn't seem to display today's reminders in my notification drawer by default. Is there a way to get today's Google Reminders to show up in your notification drawer?

Comment: Do you mean " Google Now reminders"?

Comment: In which case see https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3122344?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: I mean the reminder functionality inside Calendar: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327